# RFID spoofer with extended range

Tags: rf, coil, rfid, transmitter, power-amplifier

I have recently found [this](https://www.instructables.com/id/Stupid-Simple-Arduino-LF-RFID-Tag-Spoofer/) tutorial online about making a simple RFID spoofer, using only Arduino, used paper roll, coil wire and some passive components. I thought it was pretty neat and decided to implement the circuit myself. But instead of using NPN transistor 2N3904 as mentioned in the tutorial, I'm trying to make use of my [TLE2301](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tle2301.pdf) power-amp. I think it can be seen as modification to the original circuit since use of power-amp means that coil will receive more power and be able to transmit signal at longer distance (correct me if I'm wrong). So I'm currently trying to breadboard this and thought I would ask for advice to find out if I'm doing it right. 
Here are schematics that I made:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQaIN.png)
[image: 2]
[image]

I haven't used power-amps before and it would be really helpful to find out if this is the right way to use them.

Comment: You have a dead short-circuit on OUT1 - OUT2 and on the "ABOUT 160 uH".

Comment: @Transistor - this comment is for the op but my be of interest to you. || The original cct shorts and opens the tuned circuit to 'send' RFID data. It does not apply power to the circuit in any manner. What you are trying to do is substantially different to his concept. And, as transistor says, you are shorting your amplifier outputs.

Comment: @Transistor I edited schematic. Could you look at it and say that circuit is correct?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I edited schematic. Could you look at it and say that circuit is correct?

Comment: I checked the datasheet on the TLE2301 - Out1 and Out2 are supposed to be connected together "for most cases."  That's fine.

Comment: Russell McMahon has it right.  The original circuit **doesn't** transmit in the way you would normally think.  It changes how much of the signal from the RFID reader the coil "absorbs."  You can't really change how that works.

Comment: @JRE As I understand Arduino tunes and detunes by setting it's pin HIGH and LOW, depending on the pattern of 1's and 0's of tag ID, LOW-sending 1 and HIGH-sending 0. In my case I'm using power-amp instead of transistor so the pattern of 1's and 0's will go to power-amps non-inverting input pin which will then use that pattern to set OUT-pins HIGH and LOW matching the pattern, just like in the original circuit. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are wrong.  The original circuit doesn't transmit at all.  It is a receiver that switches on and off of the carrier frequency of the transmitter in the RFID reader.  The reader can sense how much of its signal is being absorbed and evaluates that.

Comment: @JRE Russel said that 'transistor does not apply power in any way' but it is said in the post that 'When the pin is high then it sends power to the base of the transistor.This reduces the resistance between the two ends of the coil, which "detunes" the antenna.', so in a way transistor does provide power to the coil to enable it to transmit data according to the pattern in which transistor switches power on and off.

Comment: Your circuit tries to push power into the coil, which does not help.  The original circuit does **not** inject power into the coil at all.  It only short circuits the coil and capacitor.

Comment: It sends power to the base of the transistor, yes.  But that power does **not** go into the coil.  It is only there to make the transistor connect its collector and emitter.  **No** current from the Arduino flows through the coil.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that your power amplifier will **always** detune your coil because the amplifier output looks like a short circuit to the coil.

Comment: Not to mention the coil looking like a short circuit to the amplifier.

Comment: @JRE I see. 'By experimenting with the coil winds and the capacitor you should be able to get a few inches of range.  More range would probably need some type of an amplified coil.' So how can I amplify coil to extend the read range?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: @JRE Could you take a look at this post:https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/driving-tank-circuit-at-125khz/. There the author uses power-amp to drive the coil circuit to transmit some data. How is his approach different from mine?

Comment: The author there **wants** to use a power amplifier, and is told it won't work.  If you want longer range, you need a bigger antenna.  Wind a coil with the correct inductance, but much larger.  That's what the eevblog folks told the person who wanted to use an LM386.

Comment: @JRE Alright, then that's what I'm going to do. I really appreciate your help. Thanks